# jQuery - chart animation in theory

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm planning to develop simple chart generator.

80% will be jQuery based - and I'm looking for some answers from more experienced jQuery users.

My animation will be based on:

- jQuery
- CSS
- Background images

**Basically, can jQuery manipulate CSS that often to create animation efect?**

For example: change background-position every couple of ms to create animation?

**E.G. change background-position from 'top left' to 'top right', but on px by px based?**

Have you ever seen this kind of usage?

Any examples, suggestion, technics examples much appreciated.

Comment: If this isn't just an academic exercise, don't bother reinventing the wheel - check out http://code.google.com/p/flot/.

Comment: @Matt, my charts will be rectangle demonstrating percentages (background over all element = 100%, background over a half = 50% etc.. ). Your example is for more advance usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [set the speed](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) of an animation in jQuery.
I would recommend [to clear](http://api.jquery.com/stop) the animation stack before each call.

Comment: jQuery docs: `.animate() method allows us to create animation effects on any numeric CSS property` - `background position top left = 0px 0px`, so numeric. But looks like will have to calculate element width first, than use numeric again in place for `top right`. Is this correct or top top, top right is as good as numeric?

Comment: Here is a [jquery background animation plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/)

About using numeric or text - it depends on what you are going to do

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does animation well: [see the docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

It can't animate *everything* though. If you need to do more advanced CSS animations, you'll need to use the effects that come with [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/).

Comment: JQuery UI is missing `background-image/ background-position` animation. The one I was looking for :) A port of that - perfect solution.

Comment: @NewUser jQuery UI can animate between arbitrary CSS classes, so you should be able to do that, AFAIK.

Comment: @NewUser Actually you're right, jQuery UI won't animate `background-position`, here's a fiddle to prove it: http://jsfiddle.net/skilldrick/KEJU6/1/

Comment: is the `switch ` correct way of doing this? In the only supply example on jQuery UI website they are using `.animate`.

Comment: @NewUser Either would work if `background-position` was an animatable property. But it's not :(

Answer (score 1):

See:

```
  http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/
```

See also:

```
  http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/10-awesome-techniques-and-examples-of-animation-with-jquery/
```

which lists some background animation effects.